# jquery php notification system get count variable

Tags: php, jquery

I have create a notification system using `php` and `jquery`

I have a page name `select-task.php`
this page contain this code

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT 
count(db_taskid) as sum from tbl_task where db_read='0' and (db_userid='$uid' or db_transfered='$uid')")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
echo $taskCount=$row['sum'];
$conn->close();
```

**jquery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#task").load("select-task.php");
setInterval(function(){
$("#task").load('select-task.php')
}, 20000);
 });
```

This code work fine and i receive the notification but i try to get the variable `$taskCount` from `select-task.php` page to do a verification if this variable equal to zero don't add class `not` if not add the class `not`

**this is the html code**

```
    <li class="dropdown dropdown dropdown-extended dropdown-notification dropdown-dark " id="header_notification_bar">
 <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true">Task <i class="icon-bell"></i><span class="badge badge-success" id="span"><div id="task"></div></span>
  <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="add-tasks.php" target="_blank">Add Task</a>
      <li><a href="all-tasks.php" target="_blank">All Task</a></li>
      </ul>
```

I've try to do like this

```
if($taskCount==0){echo'<span class="badge badge-success">';}
else{echo'<span class="badge badge-success not">';}
```

But i receive an error that this an unknown variable.

How can i get this error to do this verification ??!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use of this code for have a condition in your code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#task").load("select-task.php");
setInterval(function(){
    $.get("select-task.php", function (data) {
        if(data > 0)
        {
            $('#task').removeClass('not');
            $('#task').html(data);
        }
        else
            $('#task').addClass('not');
    });

}, 2000);
 });
</script>
```

Comment: please goto developer tools and trace the code, may be you are get result now, but have a problem in presentation, this is sample code and may be you need to change some presentation code

Comment: dear mohammad, we can trace your code in the jsfiddle, because we have a external php resource that name is: select-task.php, when we dont have any external.php in jsfiddle, so we can't trace problem...

Comment: here i put above the php and html and jquery code when i use your code $.get("select-task.php", function (data) {
        if(data > 0)
        {
            $('#span').removeClass('not');
            $('#span').html(data);
        }
        else
            $('#span').addClass('not');
    });

}, 2000); the class not not working don't give me the effect this effect should appear only when i have a notification number bigger than 0

Comment: mohammad, try to remove class "not" of you code, instead that,  if data> 0 use: $('#task').addClass('badge-success') and $('#task').removeClass('badge-danger') and else try $('#task').addClass('badge-danger') and $('#task').removeClass('badge-success')

Comment: i solve it your code help but the if condition was wrong i've change to if(data==0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback function with `load`:

```
$("#task").load("select-task.php", someCallBackFunction);

setInterval(function() {
   $("#task").load("select-task.php", someCallBackFunction);
}, 20000);

function someCallBackFunction() {
  if($("#task").find("#span").length) {
      //do something...
  } else {
     // else do something...
  }
}
```

Comment: i do like this but it didn't work function someCallBackFunction() {
  if($("#task").find(".not").length) {
      $("#span").addClass("not");
  } else {
    $("#span").removeClass("not");
  }
}

Comment: What is `#span`? Is that the ID of your element?

Comment: yes this is #span <span class="badge badge-success" id="span">

Comment: In that case, you should `find("#span")`.. I have updated the code.